# CSS positioning, need some advice

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

Here is my  HTML code

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="topleft"></div>
        <div id="topright"></div>
        <div id="bottomleft"></div>
        <div id="bottomright"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my css code

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#topright{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#topleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:350px;
}

#bottomright{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    top:250px;
    right:0px;
}
#bottomleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    top:250px;
    left:350px;
}
```

Here is output
http://s23.postimg.org/dhgy9mpq3/image.png

What I need to obtain, is that all 4 black square to be positioned in the corner of the red square like in this image, what should i change or add in code? THX
http://postimg.org/image/r5kv15l5v/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `#container` and `position:absolute` to inner divs.

You can combine common properties with comma, like

```
#bottomright,#bottomleft{css properties}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#container > div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}
#bottomright, #bottomleft {
    bottom:0;
}
#topright, #topleft {
    top:0;
}
#bottomleft, #topleft {
    left:0;
}
#bottomright, #topright {
    right:0;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Sb59/1)

Comment: You can write like this also '#container > div{}'. for example http://jsfiddle.net/cvE47/2/

Comment: @sandeep yes. This is one of the ways

Comment: @sandeep that will save a lot of selector junk, -Hiral, you should consider that and edit, as yours is most voted, its likely that users will refer your answer, refactoring your code is always a good thing :) though it will create a mess if OP has more `div` elements which likely has more chances obviously, so the `>` solution might not be good in that case...

Answer (score 1):

[**solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqdsf/)

**Why your css failed :** For bottom aligment, use `bottom:0;left:0;` instead of `top` and `right`....this is correct semantics which otherwise fails the concept of `position`...also, make child `absolute` and parents `relative`!! :)

```
 #container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    #topright {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
    #topleft {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0;
    }
    #bottomright {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:0px;
    }
    #bottomleft {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

Comment: That explanation is wrong. Parents can be relative or absolute, childs can be relative or absolute. They can be whatever you set them to.

Answer (score 0):

Make #container position `relative`. And div inside that `absolute`.

full code

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; //change

}

#topright{    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute; //change
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#topleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute; //change
    top:0px;
    left:0px;  //change
}

#bottomright{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px; //change
    right:0px;
}
#bottomleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute; //change
    bottom:0px; //change
    left:0px; //change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cvE47/)

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

}

#topright{    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#topleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
}

#bottomright{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#bottomleft{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following css will work

```
#container {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
#topleft {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
} 

#topright {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
#bottomleft {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    left: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    width: 50px;
}
#bottomright {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    width: 50px;
}
```